# Is Volvo a public company?

Tags: stocks, ipo

I am wondering whether Volvo is a public company. Seemingly Volvo is traded (and has been for years):

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VOLV-B.ST?ltr=1

But a lot of articles are talking about a possible IPO:

http://www.reuters.com/article/us-japan-economy-gdp/japans-second-quarter-economic-growth-revised-down-from-stellar-first-reading-idUSKCN1BI373

http://fortune.com/2017/01/06/volvo-investment-possible-ipo/

https://www.cnbc.com/2017/07/05/geelys-volvo-to-go-all-electric-with-new-models-from-2019.html

How can that be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different companies named "Volvo."

The publicly-traded company with ticker symbol VOLV-B is called [Volvo Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvo), or AB Volvo.  They primarily build trucks, buses, and construction equipment.

The company that makes the Volvo branded cars is called [Volvo Cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvo_Cars).  It is a privately-held company currently owned by the Chinese [Geely Holding Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geely).

It was all one company until 1999, when AB Volvo sold off its car brand to Ford.  Because of the history, the two companies share the same logo.

Comment: In a similar vein, the Jeep company no longer makes jeeps-- they sold the brand to Ford as well.

Comment: @barrycarter, Fiat, via Chrysler. Not Ford. https://www.fcagroup.com/en-US/Pages/home.aspx